# Data Exchange Framework - Sitecore Item Field Value Accessor doesn't work with inherited fields

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Using DEF 2.0.1 and Sitecore 9.0.1, I want a Sitecore Item Field Value Accessor to access a field that is inherited from a base template.

The default tree view for the Field property of Sitecore Item Field Value Accessor doesn't show the inherited properties on an entity. I've also tried selecting the field on the base template itself but that doesn't work either. By not working, I mean the value is not populated.

Anyone run into this? Do I need my converter based on SitecoreItemFieldValueAccessorConverter or my own reader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work well even if you set field from base template.

> "Sitecore Item Field Value Accessor doesn't show the inherited properties on an entity"

Yes. It's true. That is Sitecore behavior that comes from field type.

> "I've also tried selecting the field on the base template itself but that doesn't work either. By not working, I mean the value is not populated."

It should work. I have an example where it works pretty well.

**Check:**

- Mapping is enabled
- Source and Target accessors set properly
- Source value Transformer is used to cast the proper type for mapping (if needed)
- ...

**My test**

*Templates*

[image]

*Value Accessors*
[image]
[image]

**Result:**

[image]